# What's the difference between using a Single-expression fun vs. var in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I was debugging an issue in Kotlin and I figured that the following line is not behaving the way we were expecting: "to always return true when we are in a connected state"

`var isConnected = connectionState == ConnectionState.CONNECTED`

Changing the above line to this one fixed the issue

`fun isConnected() = connectionState == ConnectionState.CONNECTED`

Can someone please explain what's the difference in Kotlin between these two approaches? If any.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this might be the solution

Let's consider you've declared the variable when the connectionState is not connected
and try to use that boolean it would be false

but when you use single-expression fun it would return the boolean according to the current connection state

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you saying that isConnected var' value is only assigned once and would not change depending on the value of connectionState?

Comment: yes if i'm correct may be you can try by creating the `var` before you are using the function

Answer (score 1):

A small addition to the answer from Farees Hussain.

The evaluation can also be postponed until the time when the value is needed.

```
 var foo = "B"

 val result: Boolean by lazy {   
    "A" == foo
 }

 foo = "A"

 println(result)   // true
```

For the example it would be:

```
 val isConnected: Boolean by lazy {
     connectionState == ConnectionState.CONNECTED
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning this approach!

Answer (score 1):

This (your code) initializes the property one time at class initialization.

```
var isConnected = connectionState == ConnectionState.CONNECTED
```

This provides a getter for the property, so it is called like a function every time you use it:

```
val isConnected: Boolean get() = connectionState == ConnectionState.CONNECTED
```

I personally always put the getter on the next line to make it more obvious:

```
val isConnected: Boolean
    get() = connectionState == ConnectionState.CONNECTED
```

If you make this a `var` you'll have to also provide a setter, or otherwise it will just be setting a value to a backing field that you never use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning this approach!